# Which is the right way to iterate over Map and change it values?

Tags: javascript, foreach, hashmap, iteration

I have a Map like this:

```js
const map = new Map();
map.set(...);
```

How and why should I iterate over this map to archive the same map but with updated values?

Option 1:

```js
map.forEach((key, value) => {
  map.set(key, 'newValue');
}
```

Option 2:

```js
const map2 = new Map();
map.forEach((key, value) => {
  map2.set(key, 'newValue');
}
// Use map2 instead of map;
```

Option 3?

Comment: If you want to "save" `map` and create a new `map2` then clearly option 2

Comment: No, I don't need previous map values

Comment: well, then the first option ... your statement that you want to `"archive the same map"` suggests otherwise though - perhaps I misunderstand what *you* mean by *archive*